# Правильно ли использован глагол совершенного вида?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Следующий отрывок взят из перевода компьютерной игры. Акатош – бог, который является в образе дракона. Обливион – мир, в некоторых аспектах аналогичный аду. Жители этого мира называются даэдра.

> Акатош, с состраданием взиравший на тяжёлое положение племени людского, пожертвовал драгоценной кровью из собственного сердца. Он благословил кровью драконов святую Алессию и завещал, что до тех пор, пока род Алессии **останется** верен крови дракона, Акатош будет держать запечатанными врата в Обливион, дабы не допустить армии даэдра и нежити помогать врагам – айлейдам, чтящим лордов даэдра.

Мне интересно, правильно ли использован глагол совершенного вида "останется". Не лучше ли сказать "будет оставаться" или просто "будет"?

Смысл предложения: пока Алессия и ее наследники будут поклоняться Акатошу, он будет защищать их от зла в виде даэдра.